# Can I use "past tense "and "future tense" in one sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, future-tense

Can  I use "past tense" and "future tense" in one sentence?

> Although Jason went to the America last week for vacation, he will work on time tomorrow.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. If you are talking about things that happened at two different times, you certainly can use different tenses to refer to them.

Side note: "America" is a proper noun, and so you shouldn't use an article. For the second part, you probably mean that he will arrive on time. And "vocation" means your job or life's mission; I think you meant he went on "vacation". So the sentence should be, "Although Jason went to America last week for vacation, he will arrive at work on time tomorrow." (Assuming I'm understanding your intent.)

Comment: It's true that you shouldn't use "the" with "America" in this sentence, but not just because it is a proper noun. See http://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/newsletter/2011/11/using-the-with-the-names-of-countries.

Comment: Thanks for your help！ In this way， can I say“ He prepared some food before he leave tonight” Thanks a lot！

Comment: @moyeea - No, "He prepared some food before he leave tonight" doesn't make sense for a number of reasons.  Firstly, "he leave" doesn't ever make sense: it's "he leaves" or "he will leave".  But it also doesn't make sense because you can't combine tenses like that without a conjunction like the **although** you used in your first example.  "He prepared some food *although* he will leave tonight" works.

Comment: @stangdon Thanks for your help! But normally we can't put "will" in " before-clause" right? About the conjunction, "before is not a conjunction"? We can say:I will finish everything before you leave. right?

Comment: @moyeea - OK, *before* is kind of a conjunction sometimes.  And I can imagine using *before* with *will* in a sentence like "If we don't leave now, Fred will get there before we will."  And yes, "I will finish everything before you leave" is correct.  But "He prepared food before he will leave" doesn't make sense because "he prepared" is in the past, and "he will leave" is a prediction about the future -  it only makes sense to say he prepared food before *something else in the past*.

Comment: You can combine tenses, but it still has to make sense! For example, you can't say, "He prepared food after he will leave", because then you're saying that an event in the past will happen after an event in the future, which, barring time travel, doesn't make sense. Valid sentences include, "He prepared food before he left" and "He will prepare food before he leaves".